# How to inject a class in the app/console/Kernel in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to inject a class (a repository) in my `app/Console/Kernel`:

```
public function __construct(LocaleRepository $localeRepository)
{
    $this->_localeRepository = $localeRepository;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as I receive the following error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [App\Repositories\Interfaces\LocaleRepository] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Kernel]. in /home/cv/cus/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:895`

I can inject the repository in  controllers without any problem. The repository is also registered in the service provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('App\Repositories\Interfaces\LocaleRepository', 'App\Repositories\Implementations\EloquentLocaleRepository');
}
```

Is it possible to inject a class in the `app/console/Kernel` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by calling a separate method to inject the interface in the first line of the `register` method.

In this separate method I have the following code:

`$this->_localeRepository = $this->app->make('App\Repositories\Interfaces\LocaleRepository');`

Answer (score 3):

Use `app('App\Repositories\Interfaces\LocaleRepository');` to get your interface object in schedule method and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

class `app/console/Kernel` is instantiated before the app service provider is loaded.

So, I don't think it's possible to inject the class into the constructor.

However, you could use method injection. Just inject the repository into the method in which you need it.